# C++ Open File Dialog doesn't show up with OpenCv library

Tags: c++, image-processing, visual-studio-2017, clr, opencv3.0

I build windows form C++ which it contains one button to open the file then show the file text that I choose on the text box but the issue is the file dialog box not shown no idea why and am sure nothing wrong on my code.

Is something wrong in my setting?

```
private: System::Void btnOpenImage_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{ 
    //Stream;
    IO::Stream^ myStream;

    OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;

    openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = Directory::GetCurrentDirectory();
    openFileDialog1->Filter = "Image Files (JPEG,GIF,BMP,PNG,ICO)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.bmp;*.png;*ico";
    openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

    if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() ==System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        file_path_temp = "image_0003.jpg";
        txtImgUrl->Text = file_path_temp;

        IntPtr pointer_temp = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(file_path_temp);
        const char* input_location = static_cast<const char*>(pointer_temp.ToPointer());
        cv::Mat imgOriginalScene = cv::imread(input_location, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR);
        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(pointer_temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes right ty vm i accidently removed the line of code by mistake

Comment: if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )

Comment: @memi edit your original post to insert the missing line

Comment: @AlanBirtles done

Comment: it worked after adding the line  if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() ==System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {